# Trying to get this page responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling with this, I need this page content http://stirringminds.com/partners/ to become responsive but I overchanged the code and now don't know what to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2" style="position:relative;top:10px;">
<button id="showall" class="active" style="font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;border:none;">ALL DEALS</button>
<button id="show" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">BUSINESS</button>
<button id="show2" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DESIGN</button>
<button id="show3" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DEVELOPMENT</button>
<button id="show4" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">MARKETING</button>
<button id="show5" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">SALES</button>
<button id="show6" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">SUPPORT</button>
<button id="show7" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">PRODUCTIVITY</button>
<button id="show8" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">DIY</button>
<button id="show9" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">LEARNING</button>
<button id="show10" style="border:none;font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;">LIFE</button>
</div>

<a href="https://aws.amazon.com" target="_blank"><div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="businessfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/aws_logo_web_300px.png"/><span style="position:relative;bottom:15%;left:7%;color:#000;">Amazon Web Services</span><br><span style="color:#888;position:relative;left:48.5%;bottom:50%;padding-right:-100px;">$1000 credits for 1 year.</span></div></a>

<div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="designfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ameyo-emerge-logo-white.png" style="position:relative;top:28%;"/></div>

<div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="devfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/citrus-pay-e1496117866677.png" style="position:relative;top:20%;"/></div>

<div class="col-md-4 dealsdiv" id="mktfltr" style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #DDD;border-radius:4px;margin:10px;"><img class="dealsimg" src="http://13.126.32.0/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cl.png" style="position:relative;top:15%;"/></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it similar to https://startup.deals (scroll a little bit) with the vertical menu (with the words "ALL DEALS,BUSINESS,DESIGN") changing to horizontal too but when I resize my browser window, my page gets all messy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include this in your css file.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
       .row > .col-md-2 {
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: scroll;
      }
    }
```

Give a meaningful class name in the mark up for the .row or .col-md-2 and update the same in the above snippet

Comment: What about the text on the right side of the logos? How can I make them be formatted like startup.deals? My text goes out of the page :x

Comment: you mean the top navigation? or the sidebar?

Comment: http://stirringminds.com/partners/ see the amazon web services rectangle, can I make the logo and text inside that div stay vertically aligned with the middle of it when the page is resized?

Comment: The amazon logo and the others stay vertically-aligned to the middle, but not the text

Comment: you have to change the markup structure of .deals-div to facilitate that. Inspect the startup.deals.com with dev tools then you will understand how they have structured the markup

Answer (score -1):

Try putting all your div under

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

It might work :)